# When Ruby regex doesn't fit on line

Tags: ruby, regex, cucumber

When I have a very long regex, like a cucumber step definition, what would be the best way to line wrap it?

example, i would like something like:

```
When /^I have a very long step definition here in my step definition file$/ do
  ...
end
```

break up into two lines (this doesnt work:)

```
When /^I have a very long step definition here in /\
    /my step definition file$/ do
  ...
end
```

---

## 2018 update

If you're here specifically for cucumber, using [cucumber expressions](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/cucumber-expressions) is a great alternative to regexes

Comment: Use a shorter regex? oO

Comment: what do you mean with break up in 2 lines? `\n`?

Comment: You may use the `x` modifier...

Comment: @NiklasB. doesnt always work for me.

Comment: @Paulchenkiller i meant writing a single regex on multiple lines, like in the example i give (that works for strings)

Comment: Can you provide an actual example for such a step definition?

Comment: Regexes that do not fit on a single line are often a sign for a code smell. Maybe another tool would be a better fit. What does your regex do?

Comment: @TimPietzcker I dont think its necessary, the step definitions i refer to are a bit too application-specific. But, all of them have 2 or more arguments, some of them optional, which adds a little bit of clutter.

Comment: @padde I agree, though I think cucumber step definitions are an exception to the rule.

Comment: I've decided not to use any of the suggested solutions, but to allow my step definitions to be longer than the 80 characters I normally use. I hoped for an easy line continuation/concatination solution, but apparently there isn't

Comment: As long as you don't have a lot of very similar steps, you can just use something like `When /very long step definition/ do`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a [verbose regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html) with the `/x` modifier, but then you need to make spaces explicit because they will otherwise be ignored. Another advantage is that this allows you to comment your regex (which, if it's long, might be a good idea):

```
/^                               # Match start of string
I[ ]have[ ]a[ ]very[ ]long[ ]
step[ ]definition[ ]here[ ]
in[ ]my[ ]step[ ]definition[ ]file
$                               # Match end of string
/x
```

Comment: hmm, good suggestion, but i dont think that would make my step definitions more readable

Comment: @SirLenz0rlot lol if this won't make it readable then you have no other options since this is **The** way to write structured/readable regexes. Otherwise just rely on your editor and "wrap" the lines.

Comment: Old answer I know - but I tried this with and without making the spaces explicit and you're right that is required. However I don't understand why, the regex should match even if they're not explicit, but it doesn't according to Cucumber :s

Comment: @pghalliday: In verbose mode (`/x`), whitespace within a regex is ignored, making `/foo bar/x` equivalent to `/foobar/`. If you have an actual space in your text, you need to escape it with a backslash or put it in a character class.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Ah i see now - i misunderstood how free-spacing works, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

What about string to regex transformation ? You'll lose syntax highlighting but I'd say it isn't too bad ?

```
When( Regexp.new(
  '^My long? regex(?:es) that are '\
  '(?:maybe ) broken into (\d+) lines '\
  'because they (?:might )be non-readable otherwise$'
)) do |lines|
  ...
end
# => /^My long? regex(?:es) that are (?:maybe ) broken into (\d+) lines because they (?:might )be non-readable otherwise$/
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
/a\
b/
# => /ab/
```

Comment: gets ruined when I indent on the second line

Answer (score -2):

I know you want it in Ruby, but i can give you an example how it can be realised in `Perl`. I really think that you can use the idea behind this in Ruby as well.

```
my $re1 = "I have a very long step definition here in";
my $re2 = "my step definition file";

if ( $line =~ m/^$re1 $re2$/i ) {
    ...
}
```

The idea is to save the Regex into a variable and write the variable inside the regex.

Comment: its indeed a possibility within ruby. but, in case of cucumber step definitions, it wouldn't make increase readability